# N1QL query on array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the following structure in my Couchbase document database:

```
{
  "documentType": "connection",
  "id": "09690237-9ef5-4381-93dc-7312f7417f82",
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "8a282f31-5d6c-4741-909f-a84ef48571af",
      "type": "item",
    },
    {
      "id": "01f6a9eb-0d7e-4495-a90f-f96a38aef621",
      "type": "group",
    }
  ]
}
```

Numerous 'items' exists for each 'group' in the database.  I want to retrieve a list of all the items for a specific group id. For example, if "01f6a9eb-0d7e-4495-a90f-f96a38aef621" is supplied I need something like:

```
[
  "8a282f31-5d6c-4741-909f-a84ef48571af",
  "9a282f31-5d6c-4741-909f-a84ef48571af",
  ...
]
```

However, I get a whole lot of small arrays called 'entity' in separate little structures and I cannot combine them.  This is my N1QL query at the moment:

```
select array entity.id for entity in entities.entities when entity.type = 'item' end as entity
from entities
where entities.documentType = 'connection'
      and any entity within entities satisfies entity.id = '01f6a9eb-0d7e-4495-a90f-f96a38aef621'
                                           and entity.type = 'group' end
```

I am a total newbie at N1QL, so some explanation will also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY entity.id for entity in entities.entities when entity.type = 'item' end),2) as entity
from entities
where entities.documentType = 'connection'
      and any entity IN entities satisfies entity.id = '01f6a9eb-0d7e-4495-a90f-f96a38aef621' and entity.type = 'group' end
```